# SonarQube issue count is different depending on which dashboard I use

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

I'm using SonarQube 5.3 and it seems that the issue count is different depending on the view I use.

Consider [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahaoA.png) pic:

- if I look in Dashboards -> Issues I see
  the numbers on the top left
- if I click the grand total (267,877) I end up in the Issues dashboard where I see totally different numbers (bottom right)

Even on the main dashboard I see conflicting data ([pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzxmt.png))

Why don't the numbers match? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between Measures and queries run on Issues : measures are collected during analysis time and stay like this until the next analysis. Queries on Issues are updated in real-time according to the changes you do on Issues.

From what I see, we can suppose the 267K Issues is correct and you have some trouble in your SearchServer stack preventing it to be up to date.
You have to check in your sonar.log for ElasticSearch errors and be sure to have enough free disk space available on SQ_HOME/data/es to store and update your Issues.

What you can also do to confirm this, is to stop your SQ Server, clean the data/es directory and restart your SQ. Data should be consistent after that.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. Disk space does not seem to be an issue (df reports 14% use). I do have some ElasticSearch errors in my log but it's not clear what the cause is. I'd like to try out your suggestion but first can you please confirm that deleting data/es is safe (no data will be lost) as I have quite a big number of projects being scanned and I don't want to risk losing anything :D

Comment: @JamesAlexander03: deleting folders under data/es is fine but make sure you stop your sonar before deleting it.